# Is uniform convergence required for a continuous limit function?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Consider the sequence $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of continuous functions on $I = [0, \infty)$ defined
recursively by

$f_{1}(x)=x, f_{n}(x)=x+\int_{0}^{x}f_{n-1}(t)\sin(x-t) dt, \forall n\geq 2$.

This sequence satisfies

$\vert f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x)\vert\leq\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

for all $n\geq 1$ and $x\geq 0.$

I have completed the proof that the sequence $(f_{n})_
{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to a limit function $F$ on $[0, \infty)$,
and that the convergence is uniform on $[0, A]$ for all $A > 0$. But the question next asks me to prove that $F$ is continuous on $[0, 
\infty)$. I am not sure how to proceed with this since I was under the impression that uniform convergence was required for the limit function to be continuous.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Uniform convergence is not required, but it is *a sufficient condition*. However, [Dini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) may interest you

Comment: No, uniform convergence is not *required* for a pointwise limit to be continuous. Consider for instance $u_n(x)=\exp(-(x-n)^2)$, which converges pointwise to $0$, while the limit is of course not uniform.

Comment: The relevant term to search for is [quasi-uniform convergence](https://www.google.com/search?q=quasi-uniform+functions&filter=0). See also [*On sequences of continuous functions having continuous limits*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1930-032-03/S0002-9947-1930-1501551-9/S0002-9947-1930-1501551-9.pdf) by Gillespie/Hurwitz (1930) for the possibly interesting fact that a non-quasi-uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions (uniformly bounded for all $x$ and for all functions in the sequence) can be transformed into a uniformly convergent sequence by a regular summability method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proved that for an arbitrary $A\gt0$ the succession of continuous functions $f_n$ restricted to $[0,A]$ converges uniformly to $F$ restricted to $[0,A]$, so we can conclude that $F$ restricted to $[0,A]$ is continuous...

> The thesis then follows from the fact
>  that $A$ is arbitrary

Uniform convergence of continuous function is a sufficient condition for the limit function to be continuous, while point wise convergence is not sufficient in general, as Jean-Claude Arbaut pointed out in a comment above.